# How to print a block inside the node body?

Tags: 8

I need to insert a block(webform) inside basic page nodes (wysiwyg body).
How can do it?

Comment: _Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided is considered_ [off-topic](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). At least show what you already have, so we can help you with improving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Insert Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block) module. It has Drupal 8 version

Comment: Unfortunately, Insert Block is not actively maintained and it is not working on my Drupal 8.5.3.

Comment: Try to aplly this patch https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block/issues/2648496#comment-12550406

Comment: Since I didn’t see the Insert Block filter option to appear on text format configuration pages, I’ve already applied patch #33 and then I was able to activate the module. But I can’t see block inside body text. The pattern is replace by nothing. I've began to debug the module. In `InsertBlockFilter.php`, I think the issue is the `$block_id` is not found. The Array of all matches obtained with `preg_match_all` is correct but in the foreach the `$block_id` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Webform have an option to display it in a block. You dont need an additional module for that. Once you configure it to display as block you can assign it to region based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a webform block, this is when you want to place a webform in the block layout. What you need is a content type with a webform field. Install the submodule

> **Webform Node**
>
> Provides a Webform content type which allows webforms to
>   be integrated into a website as nodes.

this is an example for such a content type.